# Adding an ID to a single character

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a code which changes the color of a single character in an HTML element. (e.g `<p>This</p>` and I am trying to make the T in the element red while the other characters stay the same color)

Comment: You need to have some sort of state and some way of putting the characters on screen as the state changes. If you write what have you tried and how you failed we might be of better help

Comment: @nikoss the issue was laid out pretty clearly most people don't need any additional code

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`::first-letter` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter).

```css
.class1::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">This</div>
```

Comment: I think what he wants it to be able to control every single  character

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `first-letter` selector. This will affect to `p` elements

```
p::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

More info about `first-letter` selector:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp
2. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/

Or using `id` as you mentioned on the title, just put it in span tag and set an ID:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to surround whatever characters you want in `<span>` tags and set the css for each of those span classes separately, or just do inline styling

So if you had a paragraph with "This", assuming it has an ID assigned to it like

`<p id="yo">This</p>`

Then you can make a JavaScript function that changes the color of a particular character of an HTML element by character index

```
function colorize (element, index, color) {
    element.innerHTML = element.innerText.substring(
        0, index
    ) + "<span style='color: " + color + "'>" + 
    element. innerText[index] + "</span>"+
     element innerText.substring(index+1)
}
```

Then you can call it later on in JS on a button press or whatever

```
colorize("yo",0,"red")
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers here are great but you can also use a span tag and give it a unique id as well:

```
<p><span id="first_letter">T</span>his</p>
```

Then your CSS would be something like this:

```
#first_letter{
   color:red;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to create a js function which automatically creates spans?

Comment: Yes you can use vanilla JS or jQuery to create a new span. Here is a stack overflow that discusses how to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725248/dynamically-create-element-using-jquery